# How to load / show image saved in getFilesDir() folder in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

Loading image like below. `buf`is loaded, has the content, but `setImageBitmap` raise a warning. Any idea what is wrong with my code? `bitmap` should be not `null`.

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), body + ".image");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
byte[] buf = new byte[(int) file.length()];
int numRead = in.read(buf);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(buf, 0, numRead);
ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

**SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see Bitmap is missing. However you can do this:

```
try {
      File f = getFile();
      //e.g getFile can return a new File();
      if (!f.exists()) { return null; }
      Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
      return tmp;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't create bitmap (use Bitmap factory, see code below)
You open and read file on main thread, what slow down app. Move all file processing to the separate thread.
For that you can either use AsyncTask, or (better) rxJava library's Schedulers.io() scheduler. I'd do it something like this:

String body = "myFile";

```
    final Observable<Bitmap> imageSource =
    Observable.just(body)
        .map(new Func1<String, Bitmap>() {
                 @Override
                 public Bitmap call(String body) {
                     File file = new File(BetcadeApplication.this.getFilesDir(), body + ".image");
                     InputStream in = null;
                     try {
                         in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                     }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                         return null;
                     }
                     return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                 }
             }
        );
    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Bitmap>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Bitmap> call() {
            return imageSource;
        }
    })
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    // set result here
                    //ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    //icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            });
```